Counterexample to Shapiro inequality
Input: A positive integer n such that n is even and greater than 12 or n is odd and greater than 23.
Output: A list of non-negative integers that violates Shapiro inequality.
Winner is shortest code. Standard loopholes apply.
Shapiro inequality is:
$$\sum_{x=1}^n\frac{s_x}{s_{x+1}+s_{x+2}}\ge\frac{n}{2}\text{ where } s_{n+1} = s_1\text{ and } s_{n+2}=s_2.$$
$$\text{The code should give $s$ such that }\sum_{x=1}^n\frac{s_x}{s_{x+1}+s_{x+2}}<\frac{n}{2}\text{ where } s_{n+1} = s_1\text{ and } s_{n+2}=s_2.$$
Test case:
Input: 14
Possible output: [0,42,2,42,4,41,5,39,4,38,2,38,0,40]

Note that \$\frac0{42+2}+\frac{42}{2+42}+\frac{2}{42+4}+\dots+\frac{40}{0+42}\approx6.999995<14/2\$.

Could you explain the Shapiro inequality in words?

Welcome to Code Golf and nice first question! For future reference, we recommend using the Sandbox to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them. I can't be certain about the downvotes, but I do have some tips. I think the biggest help right away would be to include some test cases showing a few possible inputs and some possible valid outputs corresponding to them.

[Cont.] I think also this challenge could use a little more clarity, I think what I'd do is fully define the Shapiro inequality, even if just copy pasting it from wikipedia, then explain the challenge (generating counterexamples), then talk about what the i/o specs are, and then have example code/test cases. Headers can help distinguish these sections. It may also be worthwhile to include a worked example (take a test case and fully show how both sides of the inequality are calculated). These are not all strictly necessary, but they are some common things that could improve readability

Python 3, 103 bytes
lambda n:[x^65for x in[(n//2-6)*b'Ai'+b'AkCkEhDfEgCg',(n//2-11)*b'Ab'+b'AkGjQeU]TTUNRKRGRCTAXA_'][n%2]]

Try it online!
